# Call function from inside a function in Laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

This week i've decided to move from CodeIgniter to Laravel.
Atm I'm trying to "migrate" my old CI website over to Laravel.

**Note:** I am very new to Laravel, so if there's something that I'm doing wrong then please say :)
I am used to CodeIgniter, I don't even know if this will work in Laravel.

Here is how i want it to be / as i had it in codeigniter --> http://pastebin.com/DRaW0Mzt

```
        public function add()
        {
                $data['header'] = "Create New User";
                $data['title'] = "Create New User";
                $data['description'] = "Create New User";
                $data['user_groups'] = UserGroup::all();

                return View::make('users.create', $data);
        }

        function create()
        {

                $validator = Validator::make(
                    array(
                        'email' => Input::get('email'),
                        'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                        'username' => 'required|min:3|max:14|unique:users',
                    )
                );

                if ($validator->fails())
                {
                        /* If there's an error then just call the add function again */
                        /* $validator->messages(); should still be available since it is still the same "instance" */
            /* This is how i did it on CodeIgniter */
                        $this->add();
                }else{
                        /* success code... */  
                }

        }
```

If $validator fails i want it to call $this->add(); again.
Note: i have tried doing the following;

```
return Redirect::to('users/add')->withInput()->withErrors($validator); # redirect to users/add, WITH the old input and WITH the errors from $validator. */
```

Problem #1: When calling $this->add(); it call the function, but it doesn't execute the code inside the function, the view is not created and all $data is not passed to the view.

And also, IF i create;

```
protected $layout = "layouts.master";
```

It will use that one instead of;

```
return View::make('users.create', $data);
```

But no $data will be passed to it.

Problem #2: The problem with using Redirect::to(); is that IF the user reloads the page then all Input::old(); is gone since withInput() and withErrors(); uses session to store the data and it only lasts for one request, also the errors go away.
including the CSS around/on the inputs https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11204765/SS/SS-026.png

**Note:** I tried using both the following;

```
Session::reflash();
Session::keep(array(...));
```

Anyone knows a solution to the problem? or what I'm possibly doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: #1 use `Redirect::to` or `Redirect::back()`. #2 Why is it a problem? If use reloads the page, then it should be reloaded, ain't it?

Comment: If i `Redirect::to()->withInput->()->withErrors();` then 1) i won't be able to https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11204765/SS/SS-026.png get CSS around my Inputs without tons of if statements in my view files. 2) if the user reloads the page (for whatever reason) all the old input is gone, and so are the errors, because `->withInput();` and `->withErros();` utilize session, which means the data only lasts 1 request and i want it to last several requests if neccessary, which is why i also tried to use `Session::reflash();` and `Session::keep();`

Comment: 1 use single css class, no need for ton of if statements. 2 I understand that, this is how it should work - like I said, if a user reloads the page, then the page should be reloaded. That's how I see it.

Comment: 1) I would still need an if statement to determine IF i need/want to add the CSS class or not, or am i wrong? 2) yes of course, but i also want the old input to stay and the errors too.

Comment: @deczo something like this, i would need if statements to determine to determine which css classes i need to add, if the field is approved or contain an error https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11204765/SS/SS-027.png (using Bootstrap CSS just fyi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem #1

Your code is probably executing but you are not returning view form your function.

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return $this->add();
}
```

Anyway, you should stick to Single Responiblity Principale. Instead of invoking `$this->add();` move your bussiness logic to model.

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
     App::make('User')->addUser(Input::all());

     return View::make('users.create', $data);
}
```

and inside your user model add function `addUser`

```
class User extends \Eloquent
{
     public $fillable = ['email', 'username']; //protected data from assigment by user manually

     public function addUser(array $input)
     {
         return $this->create($input);
     }
}
```

`App:make('User')` is almost the same as calling just `User::`, in future in will allow you to test your code better so it is good practise to write it. You can learn more about IOC [here](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc)

### Problem #2

If user reload the page the form will by cleared, so we want you to have errors displayed?

Comment: Note sure what you're trying to do here, but i did that and i got an error; `Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException - _token`, not entirely sure how to use `App::make();` and what it does.

Comment: I've set wrong property on User Model, it should be `fillable`. You can get more info here http://wiki.laravel.io/FAQ_%28Laravel_4%29#MassAssignmentException

Comment: It seems that what you are trying to do with `App::make('User')->addUser(Input::all());` is to add the user to the database, which is not what I'm trying to do now is it? if $validator fails i want it do load the form page again and display the old inputs AND error messages. What you were doing now was to add empty users to the DB when the validation failed.

Comment: Faux pas. To quick fix just add `return` statement before `$this->add()` as I said.

Comment: Ahh didn't see that you made that change.

Comment: But at least i know to (how to) use App::make(); for that situation at least :)

Comment: Learn more about SOLID principals. It is good base to understand laravel and avoid a lot of trouble.

Comment: Didn't learn anything about any principle when studying at the university/college, seems to be a lot of new stuff to learn, experience will come in time.
Thanks for all the help :) got it exactly how i wanted it for now, it can always be improved later.

Comment: I am new to L4 too (comming from CI 2+), why would we want to validate in model? and not in controller? I find it difficult to return true/false from model with errors, with inputs. In all guides/tutorials I've seen validation in controllers not in models.

@Dym What kind of uni/collage teach PHP frameworks... I mean all the good stuff you get only from creators, and tutorials like laracast (Jeffery Way etc.) https://github.com/JeffreyWay and good documentation.

Comment: Controller should only be connect with your view and business logic. Personally, I would create repository which would take steps to handle validation and communicate beetween controller, validation and model. It is single responisiblity. One class one task. Imagne situation in which you would like to respond validation in json instead of html. Changing all controllers is bad idea.

Comment: @Kyslik Who said I'm validating in the model? i'm already validating in the Controller. We were taught CodeIgniter in the uni/college actually. Although i am a little bit disappointed with the school, there is SOOO much more and more important stuff we could've learned.
Never did we even touch Unix/Ubuntu and setting up server etc.

Comment: @estshy as i said in the OP, I'm new to Laravel and i barely know anything about it, i just started 2-3 days ago :) I'm sure i will get to create repositories soon enough, gotta learn the basics of the framework first.

Comment: You don't have to create "repositories". Create your own structure, don't be afraid of creating class.

Comment: @Dym I was talking to you about collage only, and it is great that they teach this in school I am attending uni myself but they teach us concept of MVC rather branded framework (CI, L4, Zend, Yii) we can pick one and work in it but the point is not to learn framework. And to the #estshy about other stuff. No one is certain where to write what I know it is said controller connects.. IMHO that is crap controller controlls (validates, authorizies...) and sends 'commands' to the model to either `save($data)`, `update(id, data)`, `delete(id)` and ofc `get(id = all)`. (Eloquent does it all for you)